# MsalServiceException: AADSTS90023: Public clients can't send a client secret

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-ad-msal

I've created an [issue on github](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/473) in case this is a bug.

**PROBLEM**

I'm trying to log in to an ASP.Net Core 2 Web App, using Azure AD with [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet).

When I call `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync` I get an error message.

`MsalServiceException: AADSTS90023: Public clients can't send a client secret.`.

There's not many examples of coding doing exactly what I'm doing, but [what does exist](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/blob/master/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/OpenIdConnectOptionsSetup.cs#L89) shows the `ClientSecret` being passed to the [`ConfidentialClientApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.confidentialclientapplication?view=azure-dotnet) as a [`ClientCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.clientcredential.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Identity_Client_ClientCredential__ctor_System_String_).

It's doubly confusing because the error message refers to a [`PublicClientApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.publicclientapplication?view=azure-dotnet) which is not what I'm using, I'm using [`ConfidentialClientApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.confidentialclientapplication?view=azure-dotnet).

**CODE**

Here's the full method where the error occurs:

```
public void Configure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
{
    options.Authority = $"{azureADOptions.Instance}{azureADOptions.TenantId}";
    options.CallbackPath = azureADOptions.CallbackPath;
    options.ClientId = azureADOptions.ClientId;
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
    options.UseTokenLifetime = true;

    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async context =>
        {
            var clientID = options.ClientId;
            var authority = options.Authority;
            var redirectUri = this.azureADOptions.RedirectUri;
            var clientCredentials = new ClientCredential(azureADOptions.ClientSecret);
            var tokenCache = AzureADUtils.GetTokenCache(context.HttpContext, context.Principal);

            var clientApp = new ConfidentialClientApplication(clientID, authority, redirectUri, clientCredentials, tokenCache, null);

            try
            {
                var code = context.ProtocolMessage.Code;
                var scopes = new[]
                {
                    AzureADScopes.User.ReadBasicAll,
                    AzureADScopes.Group.ReadAll
                };

                //AJ: This line is where the exception is thrown.
                var result = await clientApp.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, scopes);

                context.HandleCodeRedemption(result.AccessToken, result.IdToken);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

The error message appears to come from the server-side, rather than being generated client-side, which makes a bit more sense as to why it's getting confused as to the type of `*ClientApplication` class I'm using.

**REQUEST & RESPONSE**

Here's the request I send:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/[REMOVED]/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json
Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=006; stsservicecookie=ests; esctx=[REMOVED]
x-client-SKU: MSAL.CoreCLR
x-client-Ver: 1.1.0.0
x-client-OS: Microsoft Windows 10.0.15063 
client-request-id: [REMOVED]
return-client-request-id: true
x-ms-request-root-id: [REMOVED]
x-ms-request-id: [REMOVED]
Request-Id: [REMOVED]
Content-Length: 981
Host: login.microsoftonline.com

client_id=[REMOVED]
&client_info=1
&client_secret=[REMOVED]
&scope=Group.Read.All+offline_access+openid+profile+User.ReadBasic.All
&grant_type=authorization_code
&code=[REMOVED]
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44365%2Fsignin-oidc
```

And the response I get back:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "AADSTS90023: Public clients can't send a client secret.\r\nTrace ID: [REMOVED]\r\nCorrelation ID: [REMOVED]\r\nTimestamp: 2017-09-18 16:12:51Z",
    "error_codes": [90023],
    "timestamp": "2017-09-18 16:12:51Z",
    "trace_id": "[REMOVED]",
    "correlation_id": "[REMOVED]"
}
```

This is very close to what is described in [this MSDN Blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2015/09/04/working-with-the-converged-azure-ad-v2-app-model/) under the heading "Step 2 - Get Access Token".

**APP REGISTRATION**

I've created a "Converged" application registration, which should be using the Azure AD v2 app model.

It has a single Application Secret, a Password, which is used as the Client Secret.

It has a single Platform, Web, with Allow Implicit Flow enabled, a single Redirect URL set, and no Logout URL.

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how to make this work: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore/

I have used it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I know the post is quiet old, but I just have had exactly the same problem. I found a resolution thanks to the documentation found here : https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-credential-flows.

My code works now with :

```
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(options.ClientId)
            .WithClientSecret(options.ClientSecret)
            .WithRedirectUri("https://localhost:7001/signin-oidc")
            .Build();

var result = await app.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(options.Scope, context.ProtocolMessage.Code)
            .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, options.TenantId)
            .ExecuteAsync();
```

Be very careful to have a scope for which the user has consent and **DO NOT USE** `common` or `organization` as tenant id in the `WithAuthority` method parameter but your tenant id (the guid one)

Hope it's help !