# Microsoft oauth 2, not able to get the access token from refresh token

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, ouath-outlook

I am trying to get the access token on behalf of a user using their refresh token using the client id and client secret method, but at times I am getting 400 Bad Request stating

> Public clients can't send a client secret

Here is what I am doing,

At first I am asking the user to login and get the auth code out of it, using which I am calling the token API with **grant_type** as **authorization_code** as a response I am getting the access and refresh token, later on using the **grant_type** as **refresh_token** I should be able to refresh the access token, but unfortunately I am getting 400 stating **Public clients can't send a client secret**.

Edited: Added the API calls

API Calls

1. For getting the access and refresh token using code

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.append("client_id", XXXX);
urlencoded.append("scope", "user.read openid profile offline_access");
urlencoded.append("redirect_uri", XXXX);
urlencoded.append("grant_type", "authorization_code");
urlencoded.append("client_secret", XXXX);
urlencoded.append("code", XXXX);

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: urlencoded,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

2. For refreshing the access token

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.append("client_id", XXXX);
urlencoded.append("scope", "user.read openid profile offline_access");
urlencoded.append("redirect_uri", XXXX);
urlencoded.append("grant_type", "refresh_token");
urlencoded.append("client_secret", XXXX);
urlencoded.append("refresh_token", XXXX);

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: urlencoded,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Authentication Tab Screenshot from Azure AD

[image: Web]

[image]

Comment: Please share the request you send

Comment: Are you using `client_secret` for non web apps? According to documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token-with-a-client_secret), it shouldn't be used in a native app or single page app.

Comment: I am using the client_secret inside rest api does that count?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to refresh the access token via Postman and got the **similar error** as below:

[image]

**The error usually occurs** if you have configured Azure AD Application as **SPA** or you have enabled  "**Allow public client flows**" option and passing the `Client_Secret` to generate tokens.

- If the Application is configured as SPA, then you cannot pass `Client_Secret`:

[image]

Enabling the mobile and desktop flow makes the Application as **Public** and hence `Client_Secret` cannot be passed:

[image]

Hence, **to resolve the error** either do not pass the `Client_Secret` in the request or if you want to pass `Client_Secret` register the application as web.

**In my case**, I registered the Application as WEB and disabled mobile and desktop flow:

[image]

[image]

I generated the **tokens** using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:user.read openid profile offline_access
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
code:code
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

***Now, I am able to refresh the access token successfully:***

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:refresh_token
refresh_token:refresh_token
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

If you want your application as **Public client**, then do not pass the `Client_Secret`.

Comment: Hello Rukmini, thanks for the detailed answer, however I am following the similar steps, I do not have an SPA registered and neither do I have the "Allow public client flows" as enabled, but still I am getting "AADSTS90023: Public clients can't send a client secret."

One thing I noticed is that the error code I am getting is different that yours.

Comment: Can you paste the screenshot of Authentication tab of the Application?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46283334/msalserviceexception-aadsts90023-public-clients-cant-send-a-client-secret

Comment: I have added the screenshot in the question, please have a look

Comment: It is still the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254996/discussion-between-abhishek-and-rukmini).